# Email viewing software for Windows

Tags: windows, software-development, email

I use [smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) when I develop web stuff using my local [Wamp Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), allowing me to catch emails sent out from what i'm developing/testing. At work where i have my work email configured in Outlook when I view the messages from Outlook opens, however on both my home PC and laptop, I don't have outlook configured.

On these two, I normally had to save the email to the hard drive and open it in something like IE because I want to avoid configuring Outlook just to read emails.

I'm looking for something that I can use to view my emails or something like smtp4dev but with it's own email viewer

**Requirements**

- Compatible with Windows 7
- Does not require a net connection
- Does not need to have Outlook configured
- Compatible with Wamp Server
- View Emails with HTML formatting

**Optional**

- Compatible with Windows XP, My main computer is Windows 7 and i do some development on my Laptop which is XP, this is optional as I can put any email testing aside when i work on my laptop and do it on my main PC
- Free
- Not seperate installer for 32 and 64 bit systems, my PC uses a 64 bit version of Window 7 while XP is 32 bit, I rather a program with one installer for both, also as nothing like that iTunes where where it will check to make sure you are using a 32 bit installer in a 32 bit environment
- Can view attachments in emails, this is mainly for a software which replaces smtp4dev, with it when you open an email it's not attached, you have to go to a separate section to view attachments

Comment: pop or imap? Are the emails plain text or html?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek i'm not sure which of pop or imap Wamp uses, as for Text or HTML, i thought it would be safe to always assume html, i'll add that in there

Comment: @Memor-X what format are they saved in - the email itself may be in html or text but it could be saved in some form of datastore, proprietary format or a standard email format.

Comment: @NickWilde if your talking about the program i'm requesting i'm not fussed, i mainly need it to test that an email i sent out from the website i'm working on and it's been formatted correctly especially when it's been generated

Comment: Is WAMP important in this question? The .eml files are downloaded and opened as local files, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird/), the free and open source email client from Mozilla?

Out of the box, it will happily open .eml files saved from other mail programs such as Outlook or smtp4dev, and has a [variety of other mail import options](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Importing_and_exporting_your_mail) if you have other mail files to work with.

[It will run on Windows versions](http://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird/system-requirements/) all the way back to Windows 2000 (and yes, that includes XP).

It is capable of working offline.

It doesn't need to have any other mail program installed to "help" it.

I'm not sure what you mean by "compatible with Wamp Server" since that package only sends email via SMTP, and you're receiving it in smtp4dev. But since smtp4dev saves mail in standard .eml format, you should be fine there.

It has a single installer regardless of whether you use 32-bit or 64-bit Windows.

And of course [it can view attachments](http://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird/features/).